# Count of a query as a cron or task

Tags: python, google-app-engine

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Google AppEngine: how to count a database's entries beyond 1000?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/795817/google-appengine-how-to-count-a-databases-entries-beyond-1000)
>   [how does one get a count of rows in a datastore model in google appengine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/751124/how-does-one-get-a-count-of-rows-in-a-datastore-model-in-google-appengine)

Hi I've got > 10000 entities and would like to do count of a query. Since there going to be more than 1000 results a way I'm thinking to do it could be using a task queue or a cron job to refresh to value of the counter. That way I could use a job that takes more time to partition the count and adding parts that sum up to less than 1000. Do you agree that this is a reasonable way to performs counts that do not need to be exactly up to date all the time and do not need more accuracy than +/- 10 %? Specifically I want to display the number of recent posts where a small error wouldn't matter.

Edit: It seems counting > 1000 entities now works. So we will add these functions to the tabs ie displaying the total number of active entities and for private and company articles also number of active entities / articles. This way to count more than 1000 entities is not found in the documentation but here at another answer. We now do it this simple way that we plan to use with memcache so it only hits the data layer from time to time

```
self.response.out.write(A.all().count(100000000))`
```

that will count > 1000.

Thanks

Comment: OK. Methods have changed and it appears it's possible to count > 10000 entities this and combine with memcache for a good way to do it: `self.response.out.write(A.all().count(100000000))`