# Bigtable database design theory

Tags: database-design, google-app-engine, bigtable

I am very well versed in the theory and practice of relational database design.

I know what works and what doesn't, what is performant and what is maintainable (almost - there's always place to tweak when you start having real data).

It seems I can't find a substantial body of knowledge regarding distributed scalable databases such as Google's Bigtable (for writing apps for google app engine). What works, what doesn't, what will scale, why won't?

Sure, there are some blog posts and articles, but are there books or academic research papers on designing databases for bigtable and similar database paradigms?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> ... are there books or academic research
>   papers on designing databases for
>   bigtable and similar database
>   paradigms?

Well Bigtable is essentially a database itself, so I take it that your question is more on how to model and to some extent design your schema in these Bigtable like databases. More specifically you would like to know how to do this on Google's App Engine.

With GAE you will be using the Datastore API, which adds a significant layer of abstraction to Bigtable, so to some extent you don't have to worry about low level details as you would if you were using something like HBase. There are a few posts on SO ([here's a great answer by](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/103727/how-to-think-in-data-stores-instead-of-databases/104777#104777) a Google Engineer who I think is part of GAE team) that will guide you and offer hints on how to approach this new type of Database system.

Helpful Info:

1. [HBase](http://hadoop.apache.org/hbase/) was inspired by Google's [Bigtable](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) ([Alternate Link](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html)) paper
2. [Hypertable](http://www.hypertable.org/) was also inspired by Bigtable paper
3. [Cassandra](http://incubator.apache.org/cassandra/)'s *Data Model* was inspired by Bigtable paper
4. [Hadoop](http://hadoop.apache.org/) was inspired by Google's [GFS](http://labs.google.com/papers/gfs.html) and [MapReduce](http://labs.google.com/papers/mapreduce.html) papers

Answer (score 13):

There's not much recent literature on non-relational database design that I'm aware of - though you might gain some valuable insights by digging up old papers from before the relational paradigm 'won'.

The basic insight of databases like Bigtable is, of course, that in web-apps and other read-heavy applications, given the availability of cheap disk storage, the best approach is to optimize for reads, and do more work on writes. Normalization does the opposite - minimizing replication of data on disk, thus making writes easier and cheaper, but reads harder. Pretty much all the differences to relational database design arise from this single fact.

The other consequence - one that could use more attention - is that when you optimize for reads, you have to know what type of reads you will be engaging in ahead of time, while normalized structures are more or less read-agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

The search term is **column oriented databases**/datastores

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column-oriented_DBMS)

In the beginning there was a discussion on how to build databases. Row oriented won.

However column oriented is in a "revival" phase. It's best for big read-only, distributed scenarios.

There is much theory to find when you search for column oriented databases/stores.

Answer (score 1):

just to be sure... you did read googles [paper](http://research.google.com/archive/bigtable.html) about bigtable right?

Technologies like hadoop are based on this initial paper.