# Unique Constraint At Data Level in GAE

Tags: google-app-engine

It seems that the `unique` constraint is not natively supported in GAE, although [one can enforce `unique` check before `putting` an object to store](http://squeeville.com/2009/01/30/add-a-unique-constraint-to-google-app-engine/).

But that was in January 2009, what about now? Can I specify `unique` constraint on a column during schema creation? i.e.

```
class Account(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  email = db.StringProperty() as unique # something like this
  @classmethod
  def create(cls, name, email):
    a = Account(name=name, email=email)
    a.put()
    return a
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you still cannot specify unique during schema creation.

This issue is located [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=178&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Owner%20Summary%20Log%20Component) in case you want to watch it.  It doesn't show up on their list of [features on deck](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/roadmap.html) yet, so it seems like there are other features they will be working on first.

Comment: Supporting unique properties other than the key name would require global transactions, so it's unlikely we'll add it any time soon. For now, it's up to you to implement uniqueness yourself, through key names or 'lookaside' entities.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve a "unique constraint" in app engine's data store [as described here](http://blog.broc.seib.net/2011/06/unique-constraint-in-appengine.html). The example is presented in Java, but you should be able to apply the same concepts in python.