# Prevent duplicate property in ndb datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine, datastore

I'm building a simple newsletter app that collects email addresses. I have a form that sends the email value via ajax to my python app, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out how to see if the email already exists. The below code is currently functional, I just don't know where/how to add the "check for pre-existing entity" stuff.

```
import webapp2
import json

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

class Email(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    subscribed = ndb.BooleanProperty()

    @staticmethod
    def create(email):
        ekey = ndb.Key("Email", email)
        entity = Email.get_or_insert(ekey)
        if entity.email:  ###
            # This email already exists
            return None
        entity.email = email
        entity.subscribed = True
        entity.put()
        return entity

class Subscribe(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        add = Email.create(self.request.get('email'))
        success = add is not None 
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
        obj = {
            'success': success
        } 
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    webapp2.Route(r'/newsletter/new', Subscribe),
], debug=True)
```

Comment: You can see my solution in [maintain-uniqueness-of-a-property-in-the-ndb-database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18313254/maintain-uniqueness-of-a-property-in-the-ndb-database/49671749#49671749)

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer based on Dan's comment.  Dan, thank you for correcting me.  Further updated, to respond to updated question.

You can set the email address as the id of the Email entity and use `get_or_insert`.  Here the email storage is redundant because it is the id and also a property. You can probably get rid of this redundancy by checking another property at ### below.

```
class Email(ndb.Model):
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    subscribed = ndb.BooleanProperty()

    @staticmethod
    def create(email):
        ekey = ndb.Key("Email", email)
        entity = Email.get_or_insert(ekey)
        if entity.email:  ###
            # This email already exists
            return None
        entity.email = email
        entity.subscribed = True
        entity.put()
        return entity

class Subscribe(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        add = Email.create(self.request.get('email'))
        success = add is not None 
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
        obj = {
            'success': success
        } 
        self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))
```

I haven't tested the code above so there may be mistakes but it should lead you down the right path.

Comment: The #2 option does not work because you can't make non-ancestor queries inside transactions.  Also such queries are eventually consistent, so duplicates remain possible.

Comment: But it is a cross group transaction so shouldn't that work?

Comment: "In transactions, only ancestor queries are allowed."  -  doesn't matter what kind of transaction

Comment: @JeffO'Neill 1. It is saying there's a syntax error at the "e" in create(email): and 2. Do I need to add something in my class Subscribe to set the email as the id, or does the static method do that for me?

Comment: @user2250471, for 1, I fixed the typo.  For 2, the id is in the key and passing the email as the second argument in creating the key sets the email as the id.  You don't need to set the id anywhere else.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill - Sorry to be dumb. I updated my question to include your code, no errors, but it's still storing duplicate entries (I think the def isn't being called)? I'm very new to python and appengine, sorry.

Comment: @user2250471, no problem.  I updated my answer to show how to call the `create` method.

Comment: @JeffO'Neill - TypeError: name must be a string; received Key('Email', 'test@test.com')

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134134/discussion-between-user2250471-and-jeff-oneill).

Comment: @DanCornilescu do you know why I'd be getting the above type error?

Comment: @DanCornilescu "entity = Email.get_or_insert(ekey)" is returning the type error.

Comment: `get_or_insert` expects a key name/id,  i. e. a string,  so pass `email` instead of `ekey`

Answer (score 1):

Its a good approach to always create a separate model class. I created separate model class and updated your Subscribers class post method it will return false if email exists otherwise it will return true. I hope it will solve your problem.

```
class EmailModel(ndb.Model):
       email = ndb.StringProperty()
       subscribed = ndb.BooleanProperty()

class Subscribe(webapp2.RequestHandler):
      def post(self):
         email = self.request.get('email')
         entity = EmailModel.query(EmailModel.email == email).get()
         if entity:
             # Duplicate
             check = False
         else:
             add = Email()
             add.email = self.request.get('email')
             add.subscribed = True
             add.put()
             check = True
         if check:
              self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
              obj = {
                'success': True
              } 
              self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))
         else:
              self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/json'   
              obj = {
                'success': False
              } 
              self.response.out.write(json.dumps(obj))
```

Comment: it should be noted that this method leaves room for duplicate entries because of eventual consistency - the query may return no results even if an  entity exists (recently created).

Comment: @DanCornilescu I am using this method in my different websites and not faced any kind of duplication yet. Can you please suggest a reliable solution so that i can also update it in my websites?