# Schema-less design guidelines for Google App Engine Datastore and other NoSQL DBs

Tags: google-app-engine, database-design, nosql, google-cloud-datastore

Coming from a relational database background, as I'm sure many others are, I'm looking for some solid guidelines for setting up / designing my datastore on Google App Engine.  Are there any good rules of thumb people have for setting up these kinds of schema-less data stores?  I understand some of the basics such as denormalizing since you can't do joins, but I was wondering what other recommendations people had.

The particular simple example I am working with concerns storing searches and their results.  For example I have the following two models defined in my Google App Engine app using Python:

```python
class Search(db.Model):
    who = db.StringProperty()
    what = db.StringProperty()
    where = db.StringProperty()

    createDate = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

class SearchResult(db.Model):
    title = db.StringProperty()
    content = db.StringProperty()

    who = db.StringProperty()
    what = db.StringProperty()
    where = db.StringProperty()

    createDate = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
```

I'm duplicating a bunch of properties between the models for the sake of denormalization since I can't join `Search` and `SearchResult` together.  Does this make sense?  Or should I store a search ID in the `SearchResult` model and effectively "join" the two models in code when I retrieve them from the datastore?  Please keep in mind that this is a simple example.  Both models will have a lot more properties and the way I'm approaching this right now, I would put any property I put in the Search model in the `SearchResult` model as well.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't duplicate the properties if they'll always be the same between the `SearchResult` and a `Search`.  If a `SearchResult` should have a reference to a `Search`, keep a [`ReferenceProperty`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#ReferenceProperty) pointing to the Search.  This basically stores the related `Search`'s `Key` in the model.

```
class SearchResult(db.Model):
    search = db.ReferenceProperty(Search, required=True)
    # other stuff...
```

I also highly recommend you watch some of the [App Engine videos from last year's Google I/O](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions.html#appengine) (and from [2008](http://sites.google.com/site/io/)), in particular [this one](http://code.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/BuildingScalableComplexApps.html) by Brett Slatkin, and 
[this one](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tx5gdoNpcZM) by Ryan Barrett. They're all pretty helpful videos if you have the time, but I found those two in particular to be really great.